# Java FileOutputStream Create File if not exists

Tags: java, file, file-io, new-operator, fileoutputstream

Is there a way to use FileOutputStream in a way that if a file (String filename) does not exist, then it will create it?

```
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream("score.txt", false);
```

Comment: if anyone is looking for [Files.write()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) way of doing it, try `Files.write(Paths.get("./score.txt"), "sometext".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);`. [StandardOpenOption](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)s

Answer (score 366, accepted):

It will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the file doesn't exist and cannot be created ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)), but it will create it if it can. To be sure you probably should first test that the file exists before you create the `FileOutputStream` (and create with `createNewFile()` if it doesn't):

```
File yourFile = new File("score.txt");
yourFile.createNewFile(); // if file already exists will do nothing 
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, false);
```

Comment: if the file does not exist, how would I create an empty .txt file?

Comment: @StefanDunn with the `createNewFile()` method, as shown in my example.

Comment: The condition is redundant. According to [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29), `createNewFile()` itself atomically checks the existence of the file.

Comment: @aztek probably we could leave the condition to improve code readability

Comment: @marcv81 Needless file system access can slow down legitimate java use cases significantly, for example when trying to access a network drive. It also causes a race condition, so you can't guarantee the file doesn't exists by the time you come to writing to it. For both these reasons, it is not advised. If you want to help the reader, leave a comment.

Comment: @Robino, you are correct about the race condition. My comment was only in response to JopVernooij who was concerned about performance. But I suppose you are also right about performance anyway :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the 2nd line? The created file may be deleted between the 2nd line and 3rd line.

Comment: `createNewFile()` is a total waste of time here. The system will already do that. You're just forcing it to look twice.

Comment: Just find out that a file will be created on write, what is needed is to create the dir if not present. For that use 'Kostiantyn Medvid' method.

Comment: throws "java.io.IOException: No such file or directory"

Comment: use `yourFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()` before `yourFile.createNewFile();` if you also create directories.

Comment: @Bruno Use it *instead* of `createNewFile()`, which is redundant and wasteful here.

Answer (score 90):

Before creating a file, it's necessary to create all parent directories.

Use `yourFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()`

Update: Create all parent folders only when they are not already exist. Otherwise it is not necessary.

Comment: It isn't necessary, or needed as you wrote originally. Only if they don't already exist.

Answer (score 40):

[FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from apache commons is a pretty good way to achieve this in a single line.

```
FileOutputStream s = FileUtils.openOutputStream(new File("/home/nikhil/somedir/file.txt"))
```

This will create parent folders if do not exist and create a file if not exists and throw a exception if file object is a directory or cannot be written to. This is **equivalent to**:

```
File file = new File("/home/nikhil/somedir/file.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); // Will create parent directories if not exists
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(file,false);
```

All the above operations will throw an exception if the current user is not permitted to do the operation.

Answer (score 28):

```
File f = new File("Test.txt");
if(!f.exists()){
  f.createNewFile();
}else{
  System.out.println("File already exists");
}
```

Pass this `f` to your `FileOutputStream` constructor.

Comment: There's a race condition here...  Better to do it as follows:

File f = new File("Test.txt");
  if (!f.createNewFile()) {
  System.out.println("File already exists");
}

Comment: This is a complete waste of time. `new FileOutputStream(...)` already does that, and now you are forcing it to delete the file created here as well.

Answer (score 26):

You can create an empty file whether it exists or not ...

```
new FileOutputStream("score.txt", false).close();
```

if you want to leave the file if it exists ...

```
new FileOutputStream("score.txt", true).close();
```

You will only get a FileNotFoundException if you try to create the file in a directory which doesn't exist.

EDIT: From Java 7 you can create a file, but get more meaningful error messages when it fails.

```
Path newFilePath = Paths.get(FILE_NAME);
Files.createFile(newFilePath); // throws FileAlreadyExistsException if it exists
```

This post has many variations. https://www.baeldung.com/java-how-to-create-a-file

Comment: It throws `FileNotFoundException` in both cases.

Comment: This is woeful, so it returns FileNotFoundException when it should be something like FileNotCreatedException. A totally misleading exception.
It'd be like Stephen King saying he can't find his new book instead of saying that he hasn't written it yet!

Comment: @AriesConnolly The purpose is to create a file; it only fails if the parent doesn't exist. If anything, it should be PathNotFoundException.

Answer (score 5):

Create file if not exist. If file exits, clear its content:

```
/**
 * Create file if not exist.
 *
 * @param path For example: "D:\foo.xml"
 */
public static void createFile(String path) {
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        } else {
            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(path);
            writer.write(("").getBytes());
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a complete waste of time. `new FileOutputStream(...)` already does that, and now you are forcing it to delete the file created here as well.

Answer (score 4):

Just Giving an alternative way to create the file only if doesn't exists using Path and Files.

```
Path path = Paths.get("Some/path/filename.txt");
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
if( !Files.exists(path))
    Files.createFile(path);
Files.write(path, ("").getBytes());
```

Comment: This is a complete waste of time. `new FileOutputStream(...)` already does that, and now you are forcing it to delete the file created here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially get a `FileNotFoundException` if the file does not exist.

Java documentation says:

> Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the
> underlying platform
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

If you're using Java 7 you can use the java.nio package:

> The options parameter specifies how the the file is created or opened... it opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist...
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Answer (score 0):

`new FileOutputStream(f)` will create a file in most cases, but unfortunately you will get a FileNotFoundException

> if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason

[from Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File))

I other word there might be plenty of cases where you would get FileNotFoundException meaning "Could not create your file", but you would not be able to find the reason of why the file creation failed.

A solution is to remove any call to the File API and use the Files API instead as it provides much better error handling. Typically replace any `new FileOutputStream(f)` with `Files.newOutputStream(p)`.

In cases where you do need to use the File API (because you use an external interface using File for example), using `Files.createFile(p)` is a good way to make sure your file is created properly and if not you would know why it didn't work. Some people commented above that this is redundant. It is true, but you get better error handling which might be necessary in some cases.

Comment: `Files.newOutputStream()` does not have better error handling than `new FileOutputStream`. if you think otherwise please substantiate your assertion.

Comment: Haha, I could return it back to you: please substantiate your assertion.