# File created by try instruction?

Tags: java, try-catch, java-7

```
 try(ObjectOutPutStream utfil = new ObjectOutPutStream
               (new FileOutputStream("src/eierliste.data")))
```

Does this instruction create the file for me, or do I have to manually create the file?
  Where is src located? Which folder? What does that mean: "src/eierliste.data"

Answer (score 1):

This is a new syntax present since Java 7, it's called [`try`-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). It's a shortcut to ensure that the resource opened within the `try` is closed automatically when the block ends, what you'd normally do in a `finally` block. Quoting the tutorial, this:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
```

… is equivalent to this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
try {
    return br.readLine();
} finally {
    if (br != null)
        br.close();
}
```

Now regarding the code in the question: it's *creating* a new file only if it didn't exist before (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620718/201359)), and it's opening an `ObjectOutPutStream` for writing to it.