# Write to a file doesn't work in java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to put/save highscore in a file : *highscore.txt*

But it doesn't work for me. Anybody see why?

Code:

```
public void miseAJour(IModele modele) {

  if (modele.isFin()) {

    if (modele.aGagner()) {
      Writer writer = null;

      try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("/data/highscore.txt"), "utf-8"));
        writer.write(modele.time());
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        // report
      } finally {
        try { writer.close(); } catch (Exception ex) { //ignore }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `modele.time()` return `null`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does it throw an exception? Notice your empty catch blocks, which are probably hiding errors.

Comment: never leave your catch block empty, log the exceptions, it always assists. As other said, there might be an exception or modele.time() may be null.

Comment: Hint: "// ignoring" errors is not a very useful strategy; especially then when "it doesn't work for me".

Comment: +1 on the logging of errors - to start with you could just do a System.out.println on ex.getMessage() to see what's wrong. Second, is the path for that file correct - /data/highscore.txt?

Comment: I put a System.out.println and i saw that the error is in exception. @KevinWorkman

Comment: @AlbertoDimelli What was the error message?

Comment: /data/highscore.txt (No such file or directory) @moffeltje

Comment: @AnaVinatoru Using `System.out` to log exceptions is a very bad idea.  `printstacktrace()` or a logging library are the only right choices.

Comment: I agree that printStackTrace is better - but he's simply ignoring them, even a System.out is better than that.

Comment: modele.time doesn't return null @AlexanderPodkutin

Comment: Can't we print the timer ? @AnaVinatoru

Comment: Does that file exist? I think FIleOutputStream throws an exception if it doesn't. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620683/java-fileoutputstream-create-file-if-not-exists

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, you command a closing bracket
- Second, try adding `..` before your path name.
- Also add an catch or a null check for the `writer` and/or `model.time()`

  ```
  public void miseAJour(IModele modele) {

     if (modele.isFin()) {

       if (modele.aGagner()) {
         Writer writer = null;

         try {
           writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
               new FileOutputStream("../data/highscore.txt"), "utf-8"));
           writer.write(modele.time());
         } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
         } finally {
           try { writer.close(); }
           catch (Exception ex) { 
              System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
  ```