# Java create file if does not exist

Tags: java, file, ioexception

In my function I want to read a text file. If file does not exists it will be created. I want to use relative path so if i have  .jar, file will be created in the exact same dir. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620683/java-fileoutputstream-create-file-if-not-exists). This is my function and variable `fName` is set to `test.txt`

```
    private static String readFile(String fName) {
    String noDiacText;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        File f = new File(fName, "UTF8");
        if(!f.exists()){
            f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fName), "UTF8"));

        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);

        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return sb.toString();
}
```

I am getting an error at `f.createNewFile();` it says

```
java.io.IOException:  System cannot find the path specified
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
at main.zadanie3.readFile(zadanie3.java:92)
```

Comment: Add a println or something and debug what the path looks like. Could you also say which line of the function is throwing the exception.

Comment: If you use Java 7+ you should consider using java.nio.file instead

Comment: Why? What good is an empty file to you? And an empty String? Just catch `FileNotFoundException,` or better still let it be thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that

```
File f = new File(fName, "UTF8");
```

Doesn't set the file encoding to UTF8. Instead, the second argument is the child path, which has nothing to do with encoding; the first is the parent path.

So what you wanted is actually:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Parent", "testfile.txt");
```

or just:

```
File f = new File(fullFilePathName);
```

Without the second argument

Answer (score 1):

Use mkdirs() --plural-- to create all missing parts of the path.

```
File f = new File("/many/parts/path");
f.mkdirs();
```

Note that 'mkdir()' --singular-- only creates the list part of the path, if possible.