# ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Can someone please tell me if what I'm doing is correct?

```
File directoryToStore;
directoryToStore = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir("MyFiles");
Bitmap b = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(directoryToStore + "/" + SavedVideoName, 3);
File newFile = new File(directoryToStore, SavedVideoName.replace(".mp4", ".jpg"));
FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

try {
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm trying create a thumbnail from a video, but for some the `FileOutputStream` returns `null`.

I have checked the path of `File newFile = new File(directoryToStore, SavedVideoName.replace(".mp4", ".jpg"));` and it returns the correct path.

The video exists at the location I have given and I have permissions. I can't understand why it is gives me a null pointer?

Comment: I think you need to create file.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620718/2218897), `new FileOutputStream()` will try to create a new file if it doesn't exist already. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-):

> If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.

When you are debugging (at least in Android Studio), if you add a breakpoint and hover over `newFile`, it shows the file path. However, it doesn't show any details about the file, because the file doesn't (shouldn't) exist yet. You could try `newFile.createNewFile()` as suggested in the linked post, to confirm you are able to write the file first.