# Spring boot - load file from outside classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to load file from outside of my classpath.
The location depends of env properties:

- in dev properties I want to load file from resources folder
- in prod properties I want to load file from path (`/location/file`)

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

A possible solution is to use configuration properties and the use of `Resource`. For example, define your properties like this:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class SomeProperties {
    private Resource file;

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

Then enable your configuration properties by using the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation on any class, for example your main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

To configure the file location, you can use the following in development:

```
app.file=classpath:test.txt
```

And in the production environment you could use:

```
app.file=file:/usr/local/test.txt
```

And now you can just autowire the `SomeProperties` class within any other service. The `Resource` class has a `getFile()` method that allows you to retrieve the file, but in addition it contains several other useful methods as well.

Comment: I have something like this working.  However, how can I create the `File`/`Resource` if it doesn't exist yet?  (e.g.  Create the file when running for the first time)

Comment: @JackStraw I don't think spring throws an exception if it doesn't exist, so you can use one of the many answers found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9620683/1915448) to create the file if it doesn't exist.